# Div Appears Within Div Instead Of Under

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a div appear under another div, however it keeps displaying within the div above.

The issue is with the "Menubox" Div.

The "Menubox" continues to display inside the "header-search-box" rather than underneath.

**Here is the HTML.**

```
<header id="header-bar">
    <div id="innerheader">

        <div id="logobox">
        </div><!--End Logobox-->

        <div id="header-search-box">
            <?php get_search_form(); ?>
        </div>

        <nav id="menubox">
            <?php ?>
        </nav><!--End Menubox-->

    </div><!--End Innerheader-->
</header><!--End Header-bar-->
```

**Here is the CSS...**

```
#header-bar {
    background: #222;
    height: 75px;
}

#innerheader {
    width: 98%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 75px;
}

#logobox {
    float: left;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: 700;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 300px;
    position:relative;
    top:50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#header-search-box {
    float:left;
    margin-top:20px;
}

#menubox {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Answer (score 1):

Insert

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

between the two tags. This acts like a divider.

Comment: this works, and works well, except that it adds extra element to the DOM, better use `:before` and `:after` https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Comment: Hello, I did add the clear div however still appears within Here is screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/6ILYtGo.png

Comment: Like @Suresh Ponnukalai said, the tags header-search-box and menu box appear next to each other, but inside the innerheader. I too tested it out. Are you sure that is not your problem? I even added the clear div to test my theory. [Check here](http://jsfiddle.net/3wstnegr/2/)

Comment: Hi, you were right. the PHP call for the search form was causing the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have used `float:left` for your `header-search-box` and `menubox`. That is the reason it is coming in a side by side. Remove that and you will get the desired result.

```
  #header-search-box {
    /*float:left*/
    margin-top:20px;
  }

  #menubox {
    /*float:left*/ 
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/3wstnegr/)

Comment: I do want the two divs to be next to each other, but the second div is appearing inside the above div.  Here is screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/6ILYtGo.png.   thanks

Comment: what you mean by inside? see this fiddle. I have given different color for each. http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/3wstnegr/1/

Comment: Hello, Yes, that is how I would like the divs to display. However instead of being side/by/side the menubox is displays within to "Header-Search-box".  example: If I add "display:none; to "Header-search-box" the "menubox" div will disappear also.

Comment: In my fiddle it is working side by side and not within the Header-Search-box right. May be the problem with your inside content. Not the outside structure. Also try to add `display:none` in my fiddle, and still you can see the menubox. If still you feel not working creating one fiddle with your issue and share with us.